# Old Type C Schengen expires after type D

Tags: visas, schengen, long-stay-visas

I have just moved to France with a 'Blue Card' work permit with my son and wife.  We have type D visas (3 months to begin with) running out this week and have already applied for our first carte de séjour. As of right now, we have the receipts for our carte, which allow us to travel within the EU freely.

Now here's the problem: I have a trip planned to Dubai (Turkish airlines via Istanbul) during the time when I don't have the carte de séjour.  I have been granted a temporary extended visa for my professional visits, but that doesn't extend to my wife.

My wife, however, has an overlapping Schengen type C visa, that was granted prior to the type D and expires long after the type D.

In short, my question is: can my wife come into France on the type C Schengen?

Clarifications:

- Both my wife and I have applied for our first carte de séjour. We have receipts which act as proxy visas within the EU, but not to enter the EU (for your first Carte DS). Application for my son can only be done once we get ours because he is 7 months old
- @phoog: correct, we wish to travel to Dubai and come back to France.
- None of us have carte de séjour yet. I have been given an extended 'return visa' which is given under exceptional circumstances such as medical emergencies or for professional reasons. I was able to get a letter from my employer to prove professional reasons. My wife doesn't have this return visa.
- My son doesn't need the visa because, as a minor, he qualifies for a document called the [DCEM](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2718), which allows to travel into the EU.
- My wife has a Schengen which should still be active. It was issued in Sep'15 up to Sep'16. We got our type D visa from May 16 to Aug 16.

Comment: What does your trip to Dubai have to do with your wife coming to France ?

Comment: @blackbird57 presumably she wants to travel to Dubai with her husband, and to return to their home in France at the end of the trip.

Comment: So let me see if I have this right:  Noone in the family has carte de sejour, you all want to leave the country to Dubai and then you want to your wife to come back on a C visa.  What about the rest of you?

Comment: Updated the question with clarifications.

Comment: You may want to ask this on [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com) since, while it is about short-term travel, it is about short-term travel *as an expatriate.*  You are more likely to reach people there who have also wanted to travel while awaiting a French *carte de séjour.*

Comment: I would agree with @phoog that it may be more appropriate for the Expatriates forum but still I have to wonder.  You have a 'return visa' your wife has a 'short term visa', and your son has no other visa.  So how exactly do you propose to have him cross the border on your way back?

Comment: @Karlson the son will cross the border with the DECM.  But I have to ask Karan Kalia: what is the DECM?  I have been unable to find any evidence of it on the internet.

Comment: @Karlson I've found it.  It's the DCEM, actually: https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2718

Comment: @Karlson: A 'return visa' or 'retour visa' is an extension given by the French local prefecture to the original 3 month long stay visa. This is usually given during the time period when the carte de sejour is under process, but the person has to travel in and out of the Schengen area. It is only given in 'exceptional circumstances' like work or medical emergency. I have been able to get one because I could produce a letter from my employer....

Comment: @Karlson: The DCEM (apologies for the typo earlier) as pointed out by phoog,is a national identity for minors that allows travel into and out of the Schengen area. I have asked for one for my son, because his Carte de sejour will only be processed once mine has been prepared (mine will take 6-8 weeks, then another 6-8 weeks for his...

Comment: @Karlson: For my wife- she has the long stay visa, which ironically is only granted for three months to begin with. During this time, one applies for the carte de sejour in the prefecture in France, which she has done. Now, as normal process, once she has the CDJ, she can travel freely. But in the meanwhile, she can't because she doesn't have the 'exceptional circumstances' retour visa like me. She however does have a type C schengen which extends beyond the current type D visa. We don't know if the the type C is actually still an active visa or not, or is it over ridden by the type D.